# PostgreSQL trigger updating secondary related table

Tags: function, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, postgresql-8.4

I have two tables: `table1` and `table2`, which triggers on inserts and on updates in the same function.
As you insert a value in `table1` or `table2` a value is inserted in `table3`, with the value `table1.lastname || table1.firstname` assigned to `column3`. The `id` obtained for the insert in `table3` must be inserted into `table1.id_table3`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myschema.myfunction() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    new_id_table_4  integer;
BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
        IF TG_TABLE_NAME = 'table1' THEN
            new_id_table_4 := 1;
        ELSIF TG_TABLE_NAME = 'table2' THEN
            new_id_table_4 := 2;
        END IF;
        INSERT INTO myschema.table3
            (id, id_table4, name)
            VALUES (DEFAULT, new_id_table_4, NEW.columnA||', '||NEW.columnB, TRUE, TRUE)
            RETURNING id
            INTO NEW.id_table3;
    ELSIF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
        IF OLD.columnA <> NEW.columnA OR OLD.columnB <> NEW.columnB THEN
            UPDATE myschema.table3 SET
                name = NEW.columnA||', '||NEW.columnB
                WHERE id = NEW.id_cuenta;
        END IF;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION myschema.myfunction() OWNER TO myuser;

CREATE TRIGGER add_table3record_table1
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON myschema.table1
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE myschema.myfunction();

CREATE TRIGGER add_table3record_table2
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON myschema.table2
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE myschema.myfunction();
```

The problem is that when I insert a new record into `table1` or `table2`,

```
...RETURNING id INTO NEW.id_table3;
```

It does not seem to have any effect.
This is my first function/trigger ever, and I cannot find the error.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't update a row AFTER it has already been inserted just by setting `NEW.foo = bar`.

Either:

- Perform an update on the `table1` setting the new `id_table3` value (which is going to recursively call you ON UPDATE trigger, so be careful), or
- Use a BEFORE trigger instead of an AFTER.

Depending on how your foreign keys are set up between `table1` and `table3`, the latter may or may not be an option.

Comment: BEFORE sounds good and logical! I will try in a while and then accept the answer!! Thanks you!